# How to prewhitening the raster stack in R?

Tags: r, raster, trend

I have been using the `spatialEco` package for determining trend, p-value and tau value (raster.kendal). It was giving p-value upto 0.2 so want to do prewhitnning.
while I use kendall function for prewhitnning It is giving an error for both ASCII and GTIFF format.
(error1). when I select a file instead of stack it is giving another error (error2)

1. `ascidata <- list.files(path = "F:/ShareBoth/../ascii/", full.names = TRUE)`
   `length(ascidata)`
   `asciistack <- stack(ascidata)`
   `prewit <- kendall(asciistack, p.value = TRUE, prewhiten = TRUE)`
2. `tifdata <- list.files(path = "F:/ShareBoth/../tif/", full.names = TRUE)`
   `length(tifdata)`
   `tifstack <- stack(tifdata)`
   `prewit <- kendall(tifstack, p.value = TRUE, prewhiten = TRUE)`

that gives
**error1:`Error in y[!is.na(y)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable`**

1. `tifdata <- list.files(path = "F:/ShareBoth/../tif/", full.names = TRUE)`
   `length(tifdata)`
   `tifstack <- stack(tifdata)`
   `prewit <- kendall(tifstack$layer1, p.value = TRUE, prewhiten = TRUE)`

it gives second error
**error2:`Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ 1, na.action = function (object,  :object is not a matrix`**

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.